# Recyclerview Auto scroll issue : drag and drop recyclerview with Image outside the list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, autoscroll

I have created one Recyclerview list with nested another horizontal recyclerview and Drag and drop functionality. I want to drag image in list so i have try many code but still not get smoothy scroll and get get proper focus on Drop View. when i drag image Drag position scroll to another position.

I have attated images and video please check it

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Please check the video :
[List Drag and Drop Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDdlo.jpg)

Any one have solution?

And Code As below:

```
 mBinding.dragView.setOnTouchListener(this)


override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    val mShadow = CustomScaledDragShadowBuilder(v!!, 0.26f)
    val item = ClipData.Item(v.tag.toString())
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
    val data = ClipData(v.tag.toString(), mimeTypes, item)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        v.startDragAndDrop(data, mShadow, null, 0)
    } else {
        v.startDrag(data, mShadow, null, 0)
    }

    return false
}


override fun onDrag(v: View?, event: DragEvent?): Boolean {
    return when (event!!.action) {
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
            hideVisibleRecipeImage(false)
            true
        }
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
            manageDragEnableViewBg(v, true)
            true
        }
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
            true
        }
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
            manageDragEnableViewBg(v, false)
            true
        }
        DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
            manageDragEnableViewBg(v, false)
            showDragImages(v!!)
            true
        }
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> {
            hideVisibleRecipeImage(true)
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}


 private fun hideVisibleRecipeImage(isEnd: Boolean) {
    if (isEnd) {
        mBinding.animImg1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        mBinding.animImg1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}


  private fun manageDragEnableViewBg(view: View?, isEnable: Boolean) {
    if (isEnable) {
        val set = AnimatorSet()
        val objX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_X, 1f, 1.162f)
        val objY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_Y, 1f, 1.162f)
        set.playTogether(objX, objY)
        set.start()
    } else {
        val set = AnimatorSet()
        val objX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_X, 1.162f, 1f)
        val objY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_Y, 1.162f, 1f)
        set.playTogether(objX, objY)
        set.start()
    }
    view?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Can't help in your code without your code.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Thanks for your time. i have add some code please check it.